# Making a facebook page accessible via api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have a simple facebook app that allows someone to associate their account in our CRM with a facebook page.   The previous developer created some facebook pages which we can pull in for a user to see and link to their account.  If I create a new page, I don't see it.

When creating a facebook page, is there some permissions I need to set in order to make it accessible via the api?

Comment: Are you talking about pages the app user is an admin of, or is your app giving them a list of pages someone else (the app developer) created, to choose from?

Comment: Either way, this is likely a problem with which pages the app was given access to by the user that granted the permission, at that time. When an app ask for permission to access a user’s pages, they get asked which of their pages they want to grant access to. So this doesn’t cover newly created pages by default. Try and have that user remove the permission via their settings, and then have them login again - then they should be presented with the ability to choose from all their current pages again.